# App Icon is not showing in MDM?

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

App ICON is not showing when we place our iphone app on MDM. however is shown on MDM for download and  after installation of app, ICON is shown perfectly fine. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you talking about icon not showing on iTunes while we add ipa file in it?

Comment: We're experiencing the same behaviour. Looking forward to reading answers.

Comment: @Dipen patel not on itunes it on Mobile Device Management(MDM). its like a private space for uploading the Apps.

Comment: Which MDM are you using?